# Center text below image in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to center the Edit text below the image. This the start of the profile page for an app I'm working at so I want the Edit button text to be centered below the image.

Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TextInput, TouchableHighlight, Alert, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Constants, ImagePicker } from 'expo';

const util = require('util');

export default class TopProfile extends React.Component{
    state = {
    image: 'https://www.sparklabs.com/forum/styles/comboot/theme/images/default_avatar.jpg',
  };

  render() {
    let { image } = this.state;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.column}>
              <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._pickImage}>
              {image &&
                <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50}} />}
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <Button
                    style={styles.button}
                title="Edit"
                onPress={this._pickImage}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
    );
  }

  _pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    }
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1, 
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  column:{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    paddingLeft: 10,

  },
  button: {
  }

});

module.exports = TopProfile;
```

And this is what I'm currently getting:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's either you specify the with of the `<View style={[styles.column, {width:100, justifyContent:'center'}]}` or you wrap your `<TouchableHighlight>` and `<Button>` inside another `<View>`

Answer (score 2):

There's an error in your column style props.

You've defined `alignItems: 'flex-start'`. When the `flexDirection: 'column'`, the alignItems prop effects the X-axis of the view, EG how items in the view are horizontally positioned. Setting their alignment to flex-start is not what you want here.

Change your styles to:

```
column:{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',       //THIS LINE HAS CHANGED
    paddingLeft: 10,
},
```