# React Native - Align text in centre

Tags: css, react-native

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, Text } from 'react-native'

function RecentlyJoinedProfileCard({title, image}) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: image}} />
                <Text styles={styles.name}>{title}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    paddingBottom:55
},
image: {
    width:100, 
    height:100,
    borderRadius: 75,
    marginHorizontal:10,
    marginVertical:10
},
name: {
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    alignSelf: 'center'
}
})

export default RecentlyJoinedProfileCard
```

This gives me the following:

[image]

The text is not aligning in the `center` of each image:

I've tried `alignSelf: 'center'` style in the `text`

I've also tried applying the following to the `container`

```
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
```

Any idea on how to centre the name so its aligned in the centre rather than to the left.

Comment: The component `View`, has CSS? `alignItems` and `justifyContent` works if `flex` so If you want/can use `container: {  display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; }`

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45776759/11104068

Answer (score 1):

Why are you nesting `View` inside `View`?

Okay for your `style` to be applied on the child elements you need to give the `style` to the nested `View` and use `alignItems` instead of `alignSelf`

E.g

```
<View style={styles.subContainer}>
    <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: image}} />
    <Text styles={styles.name}>{title}</Text>
</View>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 ...
subContainer: {
   justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center'
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ->

```
        <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: image}} />
            <Text styles={styles.name}>{title}</Text>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add alignItems && justifyContent "center" to parent View to align your items in center

just update your styles code like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
    paddingBottom:55
},
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `alignSelf` to `textAlign: 'center'`

```
name: {
    //...
    textAlign: 'center'
}
```